# add inline style to div tag in php

Tags: php

The following code has no problem, I just need to add an inline style as

`<div id="nav-menu" style="width:65px;">` to it. I need your help to include that style.

```
<?php 
$pages = array('health.php' => 'Health',
               'weightloss.php'  => 'Weight Loss',
               'fitness.php'   => 'Fitness',
               'sex.php' => 'Sex',
               'mindbody.php' => 'Mind-Body',
               'food.php' => 'Food',
               'beauty.php' => 'Beauty',
               'more.php' => 'More');

echo "<div id=\"nav-menu\">\n"; 

// let's create a unordered list to display the items
echo "<ul>";

// here's where all the items get printed    
foreach  ($pages as $Listing) {

    echo "<li>$Listing</li>\n";
}

// closing the unordered list    
echo "</ul>";                                  
echo "</div>\n"; 

?>
```

Comment: You open the file in an editor, and type the code  in where it should be.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean this?

```
echo "<div id=\"nav-menu\" style=\"width:65px;\">\n";
```

OR

```
echo "<div id='nav-menu' style='width:65px;'>\n";
```

OR

```
echo '<div id="nav-menu" style="width:65px;">' . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<div id=\"nav-menu\"  style=\"width:65px;\">\n";
```

Comment: np just mark is as the solution and we're set ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<div id="nav-menu" style="width:65px;">';
```

Answer (score -1):

By default you cannot set a width for a block element like `<div>`; it takes up the full width of its container.

try: `echo "<div id=\"nav-menu\"  style=\"width:65px;display:inline-block;\">\n";`